# Instant Search/Auto Complete in a JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox

I am trying to use search in a JTable Cell with Instant Search feature so that the string entered in the cell returns matching options in a drop-down below from which user can select one value.

I've used editable JCombobox in the cell but not getting the desired result. I have to click on the cell to show options, and that too shows all the values.

If anyone knows how to accomplish this, I'll appreciate any kind of help or guidance.

```
public class AutocompleteInternal extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
public static JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();

LoginConnection login = new LoginConnection();
/**
 * Creates new form AutocompleteInternal
 */
public AutocompleteInternal() {
    initComponents();
    combo.setEditable(true);
  combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
      @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println("hello"+event.getKeyChar());
            System.out.println("hello"+event.getKeyCode());
            String comboName = combo.getEditor().getItem().toString();
            if(event.getKeyCode()>=65 && event.getKeyCode()<=90 || event.getKeyCode()>=95 && event.getKeyCode()<=105 || event.getKeyCode()==8){
             combo.setModel(fatchData(comboName));
              if(combo.getItemCount()>0)
              {

                  combo.showPopup();
                  if(event.getKeyCode()!=8)
                   {
                       ((JTextComponent)combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent()).select(comboName.length(), combo.getEditor().getItem().toString().length());
                       combo.requestFocusInWindow();

                   }
                else{
                      combo.requestFocusInWindow();
                     combo.getEditor().setItem(comboName);

                   }
              }
             else
                {
                    combo.requestFocusInWindow();
                    combo.addItem(comboName);

                }

            }  
        }
  });
}

public DefaultComboBoxModel fatchData(String ComboName)
{
  DefaultComboBoxModel modulo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
  try
 {
  System.out.println("hello");
  ResultSet rs=null;
  Connection con=null;
 con=LoginConnection.getConnection();
 if(con!=null)
 {
  System.out.println("select name from product where name Like '%"+ComboName+"'");
 //String sql ="select code,name from product where id < 100"; 

      //Object obj = combo.getEditor().getItem().toString();  
     // System.err.println("objectName"+obj);
  PreparedStatement pst= con.prepareStatement("select name from product where  name Like '"+ComboName+"%'",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
     System.out.println("hello");
  rs = pst.executeQuery();

  while(rs.next()){String pName= rs.getString("name");

     modulo.addElement(pName);

 }
 }
 else
 {
     System.out.println("con not found");
 }
 }

 catch(SQLException e)
 {
     System.err.println("Exception "+e);         
 }
  catch(Exception ee)
 {
     System.err.println("Exception:: "+ee);         
 }


return modulo;

}
```

When the entered string doesn't match available options from the database table, celleditor(JcomboBox) loses focus and no action is performed i.e it becomes useless.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, btw autocomplete with JTextField/JComboBox ism't something special, a few times in SSCCE form here too

Comment: I apologise for the late comment, but the problem persists. Appreciate any help.

Comment: I Have come to notice that the issue is with the combobox, i.e even if i don't use it as JTable editor, JComboBox behaves in the exact same manner(loses focus when the typed string doesn't match available data from the database).